# Javascript setAttribute for every second svg

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I want that  just every second rect ist rotated with my mouse move function what am i doing wrong?
How can i do my transform so that the height and rotation just change by every second element? i tried it out with if ( i % 2 == 0){}

```
function modifyRectangles(mouseX,mouseY) {
for (var i = 0; i < myRects.length; i++) {
// var sx = 1;
var h = myRects [i].getAttribute("height");
if ( i % 2 == 0){
  var angle = (mouseY) + 45;
  var sy =(mouseY/10) + 0.5;
}



angle -= 45;

myRects[i].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + x + ", 100),      rotate("+angle+"), scale(1, " + sy + ")");
}
}
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Please provide a [minimal, **complete**, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **within the question itself**. It looks like you're calculating a rotation for every other rectangle, but you're setting a transform on *every* rectangle.

Comment: how can i set a transformation for every second element?

Comment: well moving  'myRects[i].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + x + ", 100),       rotate("+angle+"), scale(1, " + sy + "), translate(1, "+(-h/2)+")");'
to the  'if ( i % 2 == 0){'  will only call it on every other svg.
This questions is hard to look at. try creating a codepen if you really want a quick solution.

Comment: would that code be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove just the condition, not the code inside the brackets of this:

> ```
>  if ( i % 2 == 0){...}
> ```

Then change your for loop:

> ```
>  for (var i = 0; i < myRects.length; i +=2) {...
> ```

Comment: You are welcome, sir. Don't forget to check the green ✔ of this post if it resolved your issue.